# Elastic search on long search phrases

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I wish to use my Elastic search index for mining the data out of long search phrases.

These phrases are multiple sentences, usually approximately 100 words long.

Is Elastic search any good at this? Is there something I should consider doing to the sentences, for example, keyword extraction, before launching a search query?

Comment: Elasticsearch can be tuned to do pretty much anything thinkable, but without knowing your problem more exactly, it's hard to help. Please show us some of the phrases you have (i.e. a sample document) and how you'd like to search for them.

Comment: Thanks. My index stores CVs of individuals. I wish to use Elastic search to find the right individual for a given job. A job has a 100-150 word description of what it entails. If I am able to filter the job description for keywords and then use it as a search query, will it be a sound approach?